# Prisma update query only allowing an update by the ID field and not anything else

Tags: prisma

```js
  const response = await prisma.teamMember.update({
    where: {
      teamId,
      userId: memberToEditId,
    },
    data: {
      role,
    },
  });
```

```js
Argument where of type TeamMemberWhereUniqueInput needs exactly one argument, but you provided teamId and userId. Please choose one. Available args:
type TeamMemberWhereUniqueInput {
  id?: String
}
Unknown arg `teamId` in where.teamId for type TeamMemberWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args:
type TeamMemberWhereUniqueInput {
  id?: String
}
Unknown arg `userId` in where.userId for type TeamMemberWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args:
type TeamMemberWhereUniqueInput {
  id?: String
}
```

Hey guys. I'm trying to update a  specific document based off of a specific value(s) in my table, but it only seems to let  me use the primary key for the table? My schema looks like:

```
model TeamMember {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  teamId    String
  userId    String
  role      Role     @default(MEMBER)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  team Team @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model Team {
  id         String       @id @default(cuid())
  name       String
  createdAt  DateTime     @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime     @updatedAt
  TeamMember TeamMember[]
}


model User {
  id            String       @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?      @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  TeamMember    TeamMember[]
  theme         Theme        @default(LIGHT)
}
```

To fix this, temporarliy I can make a separate findFirst query, and use the returned row to get the ID of the row which i want to update. This is fine, however I know it can be done without doing this, and it is  a little ugly having two queries when one can work just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prisma needs to uniquely identify a single record which needs to be updated, due to which the `whereUnique` constraint is enforced.

For now, you can use `updateMany` as a workaround for this, this unique constraint is not enforced for [updateMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#updatemany)

Answer (score 0):

As of Prisma v5 (general introduction of `extendedWhereUnique`), you can just update from `@unique` fields:

```
model TeamMember {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  teamId    String   
  userId    String   @unqiue // <-- Important
  role      Role     @default(MEMBER)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  team Team @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

```
  const response = await prisma.teamMember.update({
    where: {
      teamId,
      userId: memberToEditId, // <-- this operation will now work because it is unique
    },
    data: {
      role,
    },
  });
```

Reference to `extendedWhereUnique`:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/preview-features/client-preview-features#preview-features-promoted-to-general-availability